# Create a tsv file with data from several files

Tags: bash, shell-script, array

How can I create a tsv file from multiple files?

I want to be able to create a tsv file from several different files. One sample is associated with five 'region' files that have data in them. For example, sample1's files are: 1_region1.cov, 1_region2.cov, 1_region3.cov, 1_region4.cov 1_region5.cov, where 1_region**x**.cov is a tsv with **headers**. I am interested in the data under the header "meandepth". I want to take the value 1_region1 and then add it to my own tsv file under the header Region1. There are 13 samples, each with five region files, hence a total of 65 .cov files.

An example of my output would be:

| Sample | Region1 | Region2 | Region3 | Region4 | Region5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 45 | 32 | 33 | 28 | 15 |
| 2 | 30 | 25 | 22 | 60 | 105 |
| 3 | 44 | 50 | 22 | 55 | 77 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |  |
| 13 | 2 | 3 | 50 | 45 | 66 |

In this example the numbers are just made up.

This is my current attempt:

```
## Sample array
samples=()
for i in {1..13};do samples+=($i); done
## Regions array
regions=(region1 region2 region3 region4 region5)

## I make some variables to store data
arr=()
CountData=()
CountIndex=0
SampleIndex=0
x=''
delim=':'

## I loop through my samples array to collect CountData from the .cov files. I know the naming convention of these files and follow it.
for ((i=0; i<${#samples[@]}; i++)); do
  for j in ${regions[@]};do CountData+=($(awk '{ for(k=1;k<=NF;k++){if($k == "meandepth"){getline; print $k} } }' ${samples[$i]}_${j}.cov)); done
done

## I loop through my CountData array to collect the tuples and store them into an array
for n in $(seq 0 $((${#CountData[@]} - 1))); do 
  count=$((CountIndex + 1))
  samplename=${samples[$SampleIndex]}
  if [ $((count % 6)) -eq 0 ];then
    arr+=($samplename$x) && CountIndex=$((CountIndex + 1)) && x='' && \ 
    SampleIndex=$((SampleIndex + 1))
  else
    x=$x$delim${CountData[$CountIndex]}
    CountIndex=$((CountIndex + 1))
  fi 
done

# I loop through my array and output the tuples as a tsv
for i in ${arr[@]}; do echo $i | sed 's/:/\t/g' >> output.tsv; done

# I add the header in after
sed -i "1iSample\tRegion1\tRegion2\tRegion3\tRegion4\tRegion5
```

My attempt uses two indexes to loop through the arrays. This is my attempt to get all of the files that are associated with sample 1 in the same row, but after the first sample the numbers no longer match what is in the file, i.e; Sample2 Region1 will report 15 instead of 30. In practice this script is also only able to loop through the first 11 samples. This is likely due to the fact that I'm using modulo six in my conditional.

How can I create a tsv file from multiple files such that each of the five files associated with sample1 end up in the same row as sample1?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome, please take the tour https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: What is the question? This is a questions and answers site.

Comment: Also, what you described so far seems like being covered by paste(1) already.

Comment: My question is poorly formatted, but it's essentially how do I create this table from multiple files using the description I gave. The paste(1) function I didn't know about but it seems to do what I am trying to do, I'll try it out.

Comment: Edited question to try to make my objective and issue clearer.